# Determine length of sequences between columns or in string - and paste result

Tags: r

I'm working with data like this:

```
> df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1   1
2  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
3  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0   1
4  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   1
5  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  1   1
6  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  1   0
```

`dput(df)` is as follows

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), V2 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
                                                      0), V3 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), V4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), V5 = c(1, 
                                                                                                                     0, 1, 0, 0, 0), V6 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                      1, 1), V8 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), V9 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), V10 = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         1, 1, 1, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(V1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "collector")), V2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "collector")), V3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "collector")), V4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "collector")), V5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "collector")), V6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "collector")), V7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "collector")), V8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "collector")), V9 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "collector")), V10 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "collector")), Sequence = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

I need to copy `V1:V10` and replace the `0`s in between `1`s by the number of zeros in between. The `1`s schould be set to `NA`, so should `0`s at the beginning and the end, because they are not in between `1`s.

So, for example, row 1 should be transformed from `1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1` to `NA 3 3 3 NA NA 2 2 NA`. Row 6 from `0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0` to `NA NA NA NA 2 2 NA 1 NA NA`.

Is there a way to do this in a loop? Or might a way be to unite `V1:V10` in a single cell, matching specific patterns, transforming them - and splitting the cell afterwards again?

I have to admit, this is way beyond my skills. But I was assigned with this task and I'm grateful for any suggestions!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 pivot_longer(-rowid) %>%
 group_by(rowid) %>%
 mutate(value = if_else(value != 0 | cumsum(value) == 0 | rev(cumsum(rev(value))) == 0,
                        NA_integer_,
                        with(rle(value), rep(lengths * (values == 0), lengths)))) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = "name",
             values_from = "value")

  rowid    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    NA     3     3     3    NA    NA     2     2    NA    NA
2     2    NA    NA    NA     4     4     4     4    NA     1    NA
3     3    NA    NA     2     2    NA     2     2    NA     1    NA
4     4    NA     6     6     6     6     6     6    NA    NA    NA
5     5    NA    NA    NA    NA     2     2    NA    NA    NA    NA
6     6    NA    NA    NA    NA     2     2    NA     1    NA    NA
```

Comment: Wunderful, thanks! I need to figure out what's really going on in the if_else-statement, but it works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 5):

Define a function recalc which acts on one row and then apply it to each row.  recalc identifies the runs using rleid and then performs a calculation on each run passing the 1/0 value as the real part and the run number as the imaginary part of a complex vector to f. In f if the run contains 1 (real part) or it is the first run or is the last run (imaginary part) it is replaced with NA otherwise with the length.  Finally recalc takes the real part.

```
library(data.table)

recalc <- function(x) {
  r <- rleid(x)
  f <- function(z) if (Re(z)[1] == 1 || Im(z) %in% range(r)) NA else length(z)
  Re(ave(x + r * 1i, r, FUN = f))
}
t(apply(DF, 1, recalc))
```

giving this matrix:

```
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
[1,] NA  3  3  3 NA NA  2  2 NA  NA
[2,] NA NA NA  4  4  4  4 NA  1  NA
[3,] NA NA  2  2 NA  2  2 NA  1  NA
[4,] NA  6  6  6  6  6  6 NA NA  NA
[5,] NA NA NA NA  2  2 NA NA NA  NA
[6,] NA NA NA NA  2  2 NA  1 NA  NA
```

Comment: Cool thinking in a math way, +1!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, works perfectly! - I'm working a lot with the tideverse, but data.table seems to have interesting functions as well! :)

Comment: It only depends on data.table through rleid and that can be defined as a one line function `rleid <- function(x) with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))` if you don't want such a dependency.

Answer (score 4):

It may not be the best method to do so, but it'll work.

Adding `tidyverse` package for `dplyr` and `tidyr` functions.  Additionally `data.table` package helps in `rleid()` function.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-rowid) %>% group_by(rowid) %>%
  mutate(dummy = rleid(value),
         value = case_when(value == 1 ~ 0,
                           dummy == max(dummy) ~ 0,
                           dummy == min(dummy) ~ 0,
                           TRUE ~ 1)) %>%
  group_by(rowid, dummy) %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(value == 0, NA_real_, sum(value))) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-dummy) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rowid) %>%
  select(-rowid)

# A tibble: 6 x 10
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA     3     3     3    NA    NA     2     2    NA    NA
2    NA    NA    NA     4     4     4     4    NA     1    NA
3    NA    NA     2     2    NA     2     2    NA     1    NA
4    NA     6     6     6     6     6     6    NA    NA    NA
5    NA    NA    NA    NA     2     2    NA    NA    NA    NA
6    NA    NA    NA    NA     2     2    NA     1    NA    NA
```

Comment: Thanks, your code almost does what I want, but it seems to fail for sequences with 0 at the start and at the end. As these 0's are not between 1's, they should also be converted to NA (see the other examples).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I have edited the code to take care of corners.  Apologize for delay.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time - this solution works fine now!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do it in base R:

```
recode_runs <- function(x){
    # recode leading/trailing zeros to 1
    x[cumsum(x) == 0] <- 1
    x[rev(cumsum(rev(x))) == 0] <- 1
    # convert zero runs to run lengths and 1s to NA
    xr <- rle(x)
    xr$values <- ifelse(xr$values == 0, xr$lengths, NA)
    x[] <- inverse.rle(xr)
    return(x)
}
t(apply(df, 1, recode_runs))
#      V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
# [1,] NA  3  3  3 NA NA  2  2 NA  NA
# [2,] NA NA NA  4  4  4  4 NA  1  NA
# [3,] NA NA  2  2 NA  2  2 NA  1  NA
# [4,] NA  6  6  6  6  6  6 NA NA  NA
# [5,] NA NA NA NA  2  2 NA NA NA  NA
# [6,] NA NA NA NA  2  2 NA  1 NA  NA
```

Comment: Thanks! Always good to know how to to it in base R as well. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R option with `rle`

```
f <- function(v) {
  with(
    rle(v),
    rep(
      ifelse(replace(values, c(1, length(values)), 1), NA, lengths),
      lengths
    )
  )
}

df[]<-t(apply(df,1,f))
```

such that

```
> df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1 NA  3  3  3 NA NA  2  2 NA  NA
2 NA NA NA  4  4  4  4 NA  1  NA
3 NA NA  2  2 NA  2  2 NA  1  NA
4 NA  6  6  6  6  6  6 NA NA  NA
5 NA NA NA NA  2  2 NA NA NA  NA
6 NA NA NA NA  2  2 NA  1 NA  NA
```

Comment: Thanks - very elegant solution with little code!